# Windows Python add osgeo library to virtualenv

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv, osgeo

I just install osgeo Python library on windows
using [this fantastic tutorial](http://cartometric.com/blog/2011/10/17/install-gdal-on-windows/)

I'm using a virtualenv for a specific project so I'd like have osgeo in my virtualenv.
Now in virtualenv I cannot import osgeo (doesn't work).
What is the way?
Sorry but I'm a little bit confused about sharing library from system to virtualenv

Comment: How exactly does it not work?

Comment: I try to import osgeo with virtualenv activate and it cannot find the library. with virtualenv deactivate it works